# Stats Aggregation with Min Mode in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the below mapping in ElasticSearch

```
{
       "properties":{
          "Costs":{
             "type":"nested",
             "properties":{
                "price":{
                   "type":"integer"
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

So every document has an Array field Costs, which contains many elements and each element has price in it. I want to find the min and max price with the condition being - that from each array the element with the minimum price should be considered. So it is basically min/max among the minimum value of each array.

Lets say I have 2 documents with the Costs field as

```
Costs: [
 {
  "price": 100,
 },
 {
  "price": 200,
 }
]
```

and

```
Costs: [
 {
  "price": 300,
 },
 {
  "price": 400,
 }
]
```

So I need to find the stats
This is the query I am currently using

```
{
   "costs_stats":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"Costs"
      },
      "aggs":{
         "price_stats_new":{
            "stats":{
               "field":"Costs.price"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And it gives me this:

```
"min" : 100,
"max" : 400
```

But I need to find stats after taking minimum elements of each array for consideration.
So this is what i need:

```
"min" : 100,
"max" : 300
```

Like we have a "mode" option in sort, is there something similar in stats aggregation also, or any other way of achieving this, maybe using a script or something. Please suggest. I am really stuck here.

Let me know if anything is required

**Update 1:**

Query for finding min/max among minimums

```
{
   "_source":false,
   "timeout":"5s",
   "from":0,
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "price_1":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"id"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "price_2":{
               "nested":{
                  "path":"Costs"
               },
               "aggs":{
                  "filtered":{
                     "aggs":{
                        "price_3":{
                           "min":{
                              "field":"Costs.price"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "filter":{
                        "bool":{
                           "filter":{
                              "range":{
                                 "Costs.price":{
                                    "gte":100
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "minValue":{
         "min_bucket":{
            "buckets_path":"price_1>price_2>filtered>price_3"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Only few buckets are coming and hence the min/max is coming among those, which is not correct. Is there any size limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve your use case is to add one more field `id`, in each document. With the help of `id` field [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) can be performed, and so buckets will be dynamically built - one per unique value.

Then, we can apply [min aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html), which will return the minimum value among numeric values extracted from the aggregated documents.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Costs": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id":1,
  "Costs": [
    {
      "price": 100
    },
    {
      "price": 200
    }
  ]
}
{
  "id":2,
  "Costs": [
    {
      "price": 300
    },
    {
      "price": 400
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "id_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "size": 15              <-- note this
            },
            "aggs": {
                "nested_entries": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "Costs"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "min_position": {
                            "min": {
                                "field": "Costs.price"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "id_terms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "min_position": {
              "value": 100.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "min_position": {
              "value": 300.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Using stats aggregation also, it can be achieved (if you add one more field `id` that uniquely identifies your document)**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 15              <-- note this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "costs_stats": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Costs"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "price_stats_new": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "Costs.price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 1:**

**To find the maximum value among those minimums (as seen in the above query), you can use [max bucket aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-max-bucket-aggregation.html)**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 15         <-- note this
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_entries": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Costs"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "min_position": {
              "min": {
                "field": "Costs.price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "maxValue": {
      "max_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "id_terms>nested_entries>min_position"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "id_terms": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "min_position": {
              "value": 100.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 1,
          "nested_entries": {
            "doc_count": 2,
            "min_position": {
              "value": 300.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "maxValue": {
      "value": 300.0,
      "keys": [
        "2"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @user11037262 did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: hey, thanks for answering, your way is calculating min price of each document. But in order to obtain the max among those minimums, ill have to sort them again in my application code. Anyway to get the min/max among those minimums from the ES query itself.

Comment: @user11037262 Yes, you can find min/max among those minimums. Please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Going through it, looks like this should work. will update here once i am done with the query.

Comment: I am facing an issue, when creating buckets for min_position aggs,Only few buckets are getting created. I have an additional filter for the elements of the array. Updating the question with my query. please check.

Comment: @user11037262 if only a few buckets are created, then you need to set the `"size"` param in the terms aggregation. By default buckets for the top ten terms are only returned. Please go through my updated query and let me know if now your issue is resolved ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224774/discussion-between-bhavya-and-user11037262).